# Is it possible to copy constraints from one view to another?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, storyboard

Suppose I use Interface Builder to create UI in Storyboard with Auto Layout. Can I copy or move some constraints from one view to another?

Comment: During runtime or using IB? What kind of constraints? Please elaborate as there are too many question marks to help you. What is your case exactly?

Comment: I clarified my question.

Comment: well...how about you try it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using interface builder, some constraints will be automatic copied if you use the cmd-c or edit/copy: the ones that include the copying view hierarchy. Otherwise, no, you can't. Copy the whole view if you want to preserve the constraints.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I need to change view type in interface builder. That why I ask how to copy constraints. Copying the view will not help in my situation.

Comment: This is a different question, see my answer here please: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28626319/1758701

Comment: I changed view type by editing source code of the Storyboard.

Comment: Well, seems like this is the proper answer.

Comment: can we copy constraints from one view to another view programmatically ?

Comment: @iOSdev can i copy the constraints prgramatically to set in a view controller, actually i am making a form by generating some text box and labels and want to save in a view controller as a form any idea how to implement this

Comment: @XcodianSolangi, No, you have to create and add new constraints if either the first either the second view is different.

Answer (score 18):

Here's my hack to get ALL the constraints to copy: I have a small view within my main view that I want to copy over to another view controller, in order to do this I copy over the entire main view into the new view controllers main view. I then drag my small view (on side hierarchy) into the main view of my new controller and then just deleted the old main view that I don't need. This way you keep all the constraints for the items within the small view.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I was unable to get this to work, I wonder if they "fixed" this. Looking forward to SwiftUI anyway

Answer (score 18):

You can if you understand and learn how the XML of the `.xib` files works. I got pretty used to them and so I was able to move a view with its constraints into another view.

I'll try to explain it step by step:

1. Create an outlet for it: `myView`
2. Right click the `.xib` file > `Open As` > `Source Code` or open it in another editor (e.g. `Sublime Text`)
3. Search `myView` and you'll find something like:

   ```
   <outlet property="myView" destination="i5M-Pr-FkT" id="sfx-zR-JGt"/>
   ```

   and copy the `destination` attribute's value
4. Search the copied id (`i5M-Pr-FkT`) and one of the results will be a `view` tag:

   ```
   <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="i5M-Pr-FkT"> <!-- 1 -->
       ...
   </view>
   ```
5. Cut and paste this whole `view` tag in the needed view's `subviews` tag:

   ```
   <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ovp-8Y-qHZ"> <!-- 2 -->
       <subviews>
           <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="i5M-Pr-FkT"> <!-- 1 -->
               ...
           </view>
       </subviews>
   </view>
   ```
6. Continue searching for the copied id and you'll find some constraints that have it like:

   ```
   <constraint firstItem="w7M-JQ-JWD" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="i5M-Pr-FkT" secondAttribute="leading" id="EwH-B1-XWY"/>
   ```
7. You need to move this into the `constraints` tag of the lowest common ancestor of both superviews (the old one and the new one):

   ```
   <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="rK2-sE-P0d"> <!-- 3 -->
       <subviews>
           <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ovp-8Y-qHZ"> <!-- 2 -->
               <subviews>
                   <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="i5M-Pr-FkT"> <!-- 1 -->
                       ...
                   </view>
               </subviews>
           </view>
       </subviews>
       <constraints>
           <constraint firstItem="w7M-JQ-JWD" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="i5M-Pr-FkT" secondAttribute="leading" id="EwH-B1-XWY"/>
       </constraints>
   </view>
   ```

Comment: Great answer! I see you searching view by `id`, and what if I want to *copy* that view, not *cut* and paste? I suppose the `id` should be unique. Should it be generated by some specific rules, or it's would be enough to randomly modify it?

Comment: Yes, the `id` should be unique per `.xib` file, so it can't be the same even for a `view` and a `constraint`. I can't guarantee you, but from what I saw, it's completely random, but to be safe, keep it in the same format: `3 chars - 2 chars - 3 chars`. You can also add a new view, detect it by either positioning it at the top of the view hierarchy so you'll find it easier, either by staging the file before adding it, copy its `id`, remove the view and use that `id`.

Comment: Also, please accept this answer instead if it helped you, as the current one isn't achieving what you asked for.

Comment: I don't know, your answer provides more insight... But I just wanted to copy constraints, not the whole view. And the accepted answer is much more simple: copy view in Interface Builder, then change it's type in source code. So my final resolution is not to change the accepted answer and wait a while.

Comment: Oh, sorry. But you can still do that by changing the `XML` directly, which provides greater control than the `Interface Builder`'s automatic shenanigans. You'll just use the final step `7` from my answer and/or change the `firstItem` / `secondItem` attributes' values accordingly. Let me know if you need me to explain it in an edit.

Comment: Sure, as Storyboards are `XML` too and I think they contain multiple xib structures.

Comment: Great, I was able to copy several views, just be sure to check the IDs that must be unique to each constraint and views.